# Onclick function not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show a list of button (`PageLink`) using React. A function(`handleClick`) will be called when any of the button is clicked. I'm passing this function as a callback from a parent component (`Pagination`). But the function isn't being called. Here is my code:

```
var PageLink = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li>
                <button onclick={this.props.onPageClick}>{this.props.pageNumber}</button>
            </li>
        );
    }
});

var Pagination = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var pageLinks = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= this.props.totalPages; i++) {
            pageLinks.push(<PageLink pageNumber={i} onPageClick={this.handleClick} key={i} />);
        }

        return (
            <nav>
                <ul className="pagination">
                    {pageLinks}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        );
    },

    handleClick: function() {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-differences.html *"All DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers) should be camelCased to be consistent with standard JavaScript style. We intentionally break with the spec here since the spec is inconsistent."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers need to be camel cased. `onclick` should be `onClick`.